# Windows 10 IoT Core change DPI scaling

Tags: scaling, dpi, windows-iot-core-10, dragonboard

Is it possible somehow, to cgange the DPI scaling setting on Windows 10 IoT Core? On my Dragonboard 410c it is set to 150%, so UI controls are really large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DPI setting has been deprecated in Windows IoT Core. But generally you can change the resolution of the device(Raspberry Pi & MinnowBoard) via following options:

- Run [SetDisplayResolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/commandlineutils#set-display-resolution) command to adjust the resolution of a display connected to your Windows 10 IoT Core device.
- Change the display resolution via Device Portal.
  [image]
- Edit the [config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/README.md) on SD card of your device.You can read more about this [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5851).

For Dragonboard 410c,you could take a look at the Windows IoT Display Drivers Guide here(https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/sd410/display-drivers-config-guide-windows10-iot.pdf). The Qualcomm DragonBoard 410c Windows 10 IoI-Core image only supports 1280x720 screen resolution. It has been noted that is possible to modify the BSP so as to support the higher resolution 1080p, but no other resolution.

Comment: Thank you MichaeL Xu but none of these 3 options are possible / available on the Dragonboard :(

Comment: @andy, i have updated the reply. As far as i know, Qualcomm did not provide other solution support except 1080p and 720p.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there are no examples out there on how to build such a new bsp for the dragonboard. But as my question was related to the scaling, i can accept your answer as solution.